# What are the possible options to travel by Sea cheap, fast and best from India to Thailand?

Tags: international-travel, india, thailand, southeast-asia, freighter-travel

I am exploring various options beyond Air to travel between **India and Thailand/Indonesia**, as entering via road through Myanmar seems extremely difficult at this point due to ongoing Civil situation there. Also, I am not sure if Thailand will permit entry from Myanmar for an Indian at this point.

We wish to travel in **January 2024**, so we have time to do planning and understand if **Sea route** is possible somehow at the best, cheap rates?

Comment: What research have you already done? (This is not a shopping or wanta question so no need to close for that reason.)

Comment: AFAIK there are **no options at all** to travel between Thailand and India by sea, much less fast, cheap, best ones.  But I'd love to be proved wrong.